# Invalid color argument

Tags: python, pygame

I want to add a color to the background of a basic game but I keep getting the invalid color argument

I've tried removing `bg_color` entirely but still gives the same error

```py
def run_game():
  pygame.init()
  ai_settings = Settings()
  screen = pygame.display.set_mode((ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
  pygame.display.set_caption("First Game")
  ship = Ship(screen)
  bg_color = (230, 230, 230)

  while True:
      check_events(ship)
      ship.update()
      screen.fill(ai_settings, bg_color)
      ship.blitme()
      pygame.display.flip()
      for event in pygame.event.get():
          if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
              sys.exit()
      screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
      ship.blitme()
      pygame.display.flip()
run_game()
```

```
File "C:/Users/Areeb Irfan/.PyCharmCE2018.3/config/scratches/AlienGame.py", line 40, in <module>
run_game()
File "C:/Users/Areeb Irfan/.PyCharmCE2018.3/config/scratches/AlienGame.py", line 31, in run_game
screen.fill(ai_settings, bg_color)
TypeError: invalid color argument
```

Comment: `screen.fill(bg_color)`. The first parameter  to [`.fill`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill) has to be the color, the other parameters are optional.

Comment: You set a local variable bg_color but you don't set a slot `bg_color` in `ai_settings`. I assume that line 31 should look like the screen.fill() statement a few lines above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fill` just takes one argument. And `bg_color` is not an attribute of `ai_settings`. You need to change your line to:

```
screen.fill(bg_color)
```